# Is "accommodation" in the sense 'adjustment' only used in AmE?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/accommodation), "accommodation" can have the sense of 'a special arrangement that is made for a person or group that has different needs to others' – but, according to that same dictionary, this use is typically American. Now I'm wondering to what extent this is true – don't speakers of BrE use "accommodation" in this sense, and if not, what do you use instead; for instance, what would you call a Letter of Accommodation in BrE?

Comment: Compare the prevalence figures for ***come to an accommodation*** in [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+to+an+accommodation&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) and [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+to+an+accommodation&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3). You'll see that Brits are twice as likely to use that particular form of words....

Comment: ...but also look at [the long-term decline of the usage over centuries.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+an+accommodation&year_start=1760&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) All variations of this usage just sound "old-fashioned" to me, not particularly "American".

Comment: Thanks, @FumbleFingers Thing is, though, that "come to an accommodation" is another sense. I'm specifically after the sense 'a special arrangement that is made for a person or group that has different needs to others', as in "Letter of Accommodation", and, specifically, what a Letter of Accommodation is called in the UK, if LOA is not used there

Comment: ...and [Letter of Accommodation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Letter+of+Accommodation&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) looks especially "quaint" to me with the new trend to *capitalize* it (even the Victorians with their propensity for capitalizing Important Words didn't usually do it for that one).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Haha, ok :) So, what would you call it instead then?

Comment: In Britain (illegal immigrants excepted), the idea that some special "subsection" of society should be treated differently (sent to live on the reservation, for example) generally wouldn't be tolerated, so any such document would be unlikely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Huh? Now you've lost me! I'm talking about the letter you get to get accommodations as a student with a disability, for instance

Comment: @FumbleFingers see this, for instance: https://access.highline.edu/faq-items/what-is-a-letter-of-accommodation/

Comment: from your link: *letter of accommodation (LOA) is a plan for academic accommodations. Section 504 of the Rehabilitation Act of 1973 and the **Americans with Disabilities Act of 1990** protect students from discrimination*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for the British English terminology for an American document that has no British equivalent. And it's just a matter of administrative procedures anyway, not *use of the English language* as such.

Comment: We'd call it ***American paprerwork***

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh... but... don't you have the equivalent situation in the UK? Making adjustments for disabled students?

Comment: we have green cards and blue cards and badges and stuff. but we don't tend to attach much importance to pieces of paper as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok – thanks for clearing this up! :)

Comment: There is a thing in Britain,  an EHCP, which is a Education and Health Care Plan, for children and young adults (up to 25) specifying their need and requiring that institutions take certain steps to meet those needs.  The is analogous document in the law in England (and I think Scotland too)  @FumbleFingers is wrong.  We attach great importance to such pieces of paper, because Ofsted will check.

Comment: There's a Wikipedia article "Reasonable Accommodation" that covers regulations in UK, Canada and US, so the phrase must have some currency.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasonable_accommodation

Answer (score 2):

I tend to disagree with the Cambridge dictionary in marking this as exclusively American.  I can find examples of this sense used in British writing:

> [Pregnancy and maternity discrimination] takes many forms, including [...] refusing to offer reasonable accommodations to help expectant mothers do their jobs. As a pregnant woman or new mum, you must understand your rights ... ([source](https://investinginwomen.co.uk/employment-rights-pregnancy-and-maternity-leave/))

Note the British "mum" in this example.

A LOA is the name of a legal document.  It is defined in US law.  The equivalent in English law would be the EHCP (Education and Health Care Plan)  which was previously (before 2014) called a "Statement of Special Educational Needs" - resulting in the rather ugly expression "statemented". Note that these are legal terms and so jurisdiction matters. The law changed in 2014, but the new law only applies to England, not to Wales (which continues to have Statements, not EHCPs) and Scotland is different again, since it has a completely separate education and legal system.

Both Letter of Accommodation and Education and Health Care Plan are proper nouns, and so fixed.  You don't adapt proper nouns to dialect.

If you are in another country, the usual approach is to use the name of the document untranslated, with a literal translation for convenience (Eg "*Koseki Tohon* (family register)" for the legal document in Japan).  If you are in a country in which there is no such document, but this is just an informal set of suggests for how to accommodate someone, you can just use descriptive language.  This document would likely take the form of a "list" so:

> I'll send you a list of the accommodations you should make to support this disabled person.

Comment: Thank you so much, James!! I didn't realise that LOA is in itself a legal document – I certainly can't use that then... Nor can I use EHCP, for the same reason. I found that the University of Edinburgh (https://www.ed.ac.uk/student-disability-service/students/factsheets/schedule-of-adjustments ) uses "Schedule of Adjustments" for exactly the kind of document I mean: "To ensure you receive the support you require, we need to communicate information regarding your requirements to staff across the University.  We do this by creating Schedule of Adjustments (SoA). ... A SoA is an electronic ...

Comment: ... [cont.] document that lists the adjustments that the Student Disability Service recommend should be made for you by the University e.g. extra time in exams, copies of lecture slides etc." Like I said, this is **exactly** what I'm after. I haven't found this anywhere else except at the University of Edinburgh though, so I'm wondering if there is another name that is more commonly used for this kind of document?

Comment: Edinburgh is Scotland, that's a whole different **country**! The names of things will be different in a different system like Scotland's system.  Probably SoA is the name in the Scottish system.  I would expect an EHCP to indicate things like "extra time" or "copies of slides"

Comment: Oh yes – my bad! Anyway, I need a name for this kind of document that would make sense in BrE, but that isn't the name of an actual legal document, since it's to be used for a non-legal document in a non-English speaking country. So, basically, if you were just to give this kind of document a name that made sense in BrE, what would you call it? Perhaps just "letter of adjustments"? Or something else?

Comment: You can just use descriptive language.  "A list of the accommodations you should make".

Comment: Thing is, I'm translating a text for students with a disability, which is similar to the University of Edinburgh text I linked to, where the document is first explained (in much the same way as it is in the U of E text), and then referred back to throughout the text. When the document is first introduced, I obviously just describe it, but it gets a bit weird to use "the document listing the accommodations that you are entitled to" or the like every time I subsequently refer back to the document. That's why I need something like "letter of adjustments" or the like...

Comment: And what's more – it's not just that it gets weird to use a long descriptive phrase every time, it's also that I need something that has an official-sounding name, if you see what I mean. So just "list of adjustments" doesn't really work even though it's reasonably short. (I do hope you see what I mean, and I'm very, very grateful for your time and your help!)

Comment: Honestly, no I don't see the problem.  If you are translating something, then just use the literal translation, or even the untranslated text (with translation gloss like the koseki example) Or give a longer description on the first use of the term and then a short form like "list of accommodations" on each subsequent use.  You can't have this both ways! either it is an official legal document, or it is something informal.  Either the person must make these accommodations by law, or it is merely something they ought to do.

Comment: Yeah, I'll think of something – thank you so much for taking the time!